# While migrating huge database in GCP, BigTable created from sequence file created from another BigTable having different size

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I have a huge database stored in Bigtable in GCP. I am migrating the bigtable data from one account to another GCP Account using DataFlow so, creating a sequence file from a bigtable and accessing it from another account using dataflow. but the new table created is having different size than the original table. Already Storing bigtable's sequence file and temporary files at different bucket locations so that it(dataflow) does not upload any un-necessary data into new bigtable. Original bigtable size is 321.7 GB but the new table is showing 340.7 GB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data needs to be [compacted/compressed](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/overview#compression) which will happen automatically. If you just did the migration, over the next few days the backend should handle that for you and you should see a more similar table size.

Comment: Okay, so I hope backend does that for me. If it does, I will update it here.. And also on same believe we had migrated another bigtable yesterday following the same dataflow i.e., creating sequence files from bigtable using the dataflow and then creating bigtable and adding data into another account from the sequence file using the dataflow .. the original size of bigtable was 561.9 GB but the migrated table is of 638.6 GB..

Comment: yeah its actually working. Thanks for the help.